# read text file delimited by enter in a dataset in C#

Tags: c#, string, dataset

I need read a text file delimited by enter i.e each line is having a new entry.

e.g.

```
101153,E006,"\n"  
101153,E016,"\n"  
101153,E026,"\n"  
101153,E035,"\n"  
101153,N006,"\n"  
101153,N016,2
```

how can i read these kind of records in a data-set .?

Comment: What type of dataset? What have you tried so far?

Comment: netr ? whats that? @Ankur

Comment: @ChrisMantle : Actually I have not done it before. What I have done is read these kind of records in a text file. I have never this kind of coding before, so have no idea how it can be done.

Comment: I think `new line character` , Is it ?

Comment: @loy : Actually it is enter. New line.

Comment: @zey : Yes it is  new line

Comment: What do you want to do ? `Read from text file and add to data-set ` ? or `read from data-set` ?

Comment: @zey : I want to read from the text file and add it to the dataset, so that my trip will be saved as I am reading the records from the text file coming back to my code updating nad going back to fetch from the file. If i add everythin to the dataset I will not have to go to the drive , locate file and read from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This my snippet code: **How to read text file delimited by netr**

```
string[] dataFile = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add();
DataRow dr;

dt.Columns.Add("column1"); 
dt.Columns.Add("column2");
dt.Columns.Add("column3");

if (dataFile.Count() > 0)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < dataFile.Count(); x++)
    {       
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataFile[x]))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() != -1)
            {
                string[] fields;
                fields = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                if (fields.Count() == 3) // 3 columns
                {
                     dr = dt.NewDataRow();
                     dr["column1"] = fields[0];
                     dr["column2"] = fields[1];
                     dr["column3"] = fields[2];
                     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

**Reference:** [Code: Reading a Text File One Line at a Time (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: loy , `file.ReadLine()` may be enough for him :)

Comment: I agree with @zey. Nevertheless, +1. Good job.

Comment: I second to you @ChristianMark...like a charm

Answer (score 0):

To load this into a dataset, you will have to go through the following steps.

1. Create a new `DataTable`. Then define the `DataColumns` for the `DataTable`.
2. Then read the textfile line by line and split the line and insert into the `DataTable`. You can use the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method to split the line by `,`.

The code at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx has everything you need to help with loading the `DataSet`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx for reading files.